# WSDL: Read value from properties file

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, wsdl

i have wsdl file under web-inf/wsdl and i want to read value from property file in wsdl as follows:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://ws.com/" 
schemaLocation="${ws.url}">
</xs:import>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Eg: URL.properties

```
ws.url=http://localhost:8080/WS/xsd/WS.xsd
```

Spring.xml

```
<sws:static-wsdl id="MyWSService" location="/web-inf/wsdl/MyWS.wsdl"/>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: That isn't possible... Why would you want that?

Comment: we want to make it configurable

Comment: Why? You simply cannot do that, it is static.

Comment: Can we do it in maven ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven to [filter properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) in static files during the build process.  For your example, you could replace the `${ws.url}` placeholder in your WSDL with the corresponding value from your properties file by including something similar to the following in your POM:

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/config/URL.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <!-- replace matching URL.properties in MyWS.wsdl -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>WEB-INF/wsdl/MyWS.wsdl</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <!-- include all other webapp content unfiltered, to avoid corrupting content -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/wsdl/MyWS.wsdl</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```